# Is it possible to keep setInterval on multiple devices 'synced' by compensating for drift, or do I need server synchronisation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a React Native app where my entire back end is provided for by services like Firebase etc.

The app requires clocks on multiple devices to start and end at the same time which can run for up to an hour.

Given a shared starting point in time between devices I have observed drift in the accuracy of `setInterval` in this 20 seconds of data:

[image]

I am attempting to compensate for this deviation in clock timing by measuring it and then compensating for it - [here is a code sandbox with my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mayer-pvfi3?file=/src/useTimer.js).

`useTimer` hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

export const convertMsToMinsAndSecs = (countDown) => {
  const seconds = moment
    .duration(countDown)
    .seconds()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, "0");
  const minutes = moment
    .duration(countDown)
    .minutes()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, "0");
  const minsAndSecs = `${minutes.toString()}:${seconds.toString()}`;
  return countDown > 0 ? minsAndSecs : "00:00";
};

const roundTimeStamp = (timeStamp) =>
  timeStamp === 0 ? 0 : timeStamp + (1000 - (timeStamp % 1000));

export const useTimer = (
  started,
  startTime,
  length,
  resetClock,
  clockIntialState
) => {
  const initialTimerState = {
    start: 0,
    end: 0,
    timeNow: 0,
    remaining: length,
    clock: convertMsToMinsAndSecs(length),
    internalClockDeviation: 0
  };
  const [timeData, setTimeData] = useState(initialTimerState);

  const intervalId = useRef(null);
  const deviation = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      start: roundTimeStamp(startTime),
      end: roundTimeStamp(startTime) + length
    }));
    if (started) {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
        const intervalTime = moment().valueOf();
        setTimeData((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            timeNow: intervalTime,
            remaining: prevState.remaining - 1000,
            clock: convertMsToMinsAndSecs(prevState.remaining - 1000),
            internalClockDeviation:
              prevState.timeNow === 0
                ? 0
                : intervalTime - prevState.timeNow - 1000
          };
        });
      }, 1000 - deviation.current);
    }
  }, [started]);

  useEffect(() => {
    deviation.current = timeData.internalClockDeviation;
  }, [timeData.internalClockDeviation]);

  if (timeData.remaining <= 0 && started) {
    resetClock(clockIntialState);
    clearTimeout(intervalId.current);
    setTimeData(initialTimerState);
  }
  const compensatedLength = 1000 - deviation.current;
  return {
    timeData,
    intervalId,
    compensatedLength,
    setTimeData,
    initialTimerState
  };
};
```

As I am not running my own server application I would prefer to handle this on the client side if possible. It also means that I do not need to rely on network connections or the availability of a timing server.

Will my approach work across multiple devices, and if so can it be improved, or do I need to build a server side application to effectively handle this? TIA.

Comment: And you realize that calls to the server all have latency so the correction will also be off. Typically if you need an exact time you are just using timeout/interval to get you there and you are doing a diff off the time you get from the clock. All that is destroyed if the user changes the computer's time. :)

Comment: Yup thanks - but I know there are techniques for compensating for that too

Comment: Ok thanks understood - so I could make an api call to get the time and I could use that to calculate the diff?

Answer (score 3):

When you determine time diff you can not rely on intervals being accurate. Gets worse when tab is in background/not in focus.

Typically you rely on timestamps to get the offset in time, you do not subtract a fix number.

```js
function countDown(totalTime, onComplete, onUpdate, delay = 1000) {
  let timer;
  const startTime = new Date().getTime();
  function next() {
    const runningTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    let remaining = Math.max(totalTime - runningTime, 0);
    onUpdate && onUpdate(remaining);
    !remaining && onComplete && onComplete();
    var ms = Math.min(delay, remaining);
    timer = remaining && window.setTimeout(next, ms);
  }
  
  next()

  return function () {
    timer && window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }

}

countDown(5000, function(){ console.log('done1'); }, function(x){ console.log('update1 ', x); }); 

const out = document.getElementById("out");
const cd = countDown(
  60000, 
  function(){ out.textContent = 'done'; }, 
  function(x){ out.textContent = (x/1000).toFixed(3); },
  20
);
 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', cd);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<button id="btn">stop</button>
```

This will fail if user changes clock, not much you can do on that. You could ping the server for time, but that also has latency with how long the call takes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to try and adapt for React Native and see how I get on..

Comment: One question - can you explain how this differs from the example in my sandbox? It seems like they are every similar in that I'm measuring the difference every second and compensating for it, although the compensation is one second behind.

Comment: My code I do not care about how much it is off until the end. The amount of time each interval runs does not matter. If you need each update call to be almost the same time, then yes you will need to compensate for each difference on update I would approach it a bit differently than you did.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can synchronize all the clocks together is having all of them observe one single source of truth.

If you create the timestamp on one client. You need to make sure all the other clients are in sync with that data.

What you can do is have a server + client architecture where the server is the single point of truth. But if you are trying to completely synchronize without a single point of truth, you are doomed to fail because of the problems that you can not control like latency of communication between all the client applications in your case clock.